# How to Handle Authentication Errors in Python Flask?

Tags: python, authentication, flask, error-handling, flask-login

I'm working on a Python Flask web application that requires user authentication. I've implemented a basic authentication system using Flask-Login, but I'm encountering some issues with handling authentication errors. Specifically, when a user enters incorrect credentials, I want to display a custom error message and redirect them to the login page.

Here's a summary of what I've done so far:

I've created a User model and integrated Flask-Login for session management.
I've set up a login route that handles user login and redirects to the dashboard on success.
However, when a user enters incorrect credentials, Flask-Login's default behavior displays a generic "Invalid username or password" message. I want to replace this message with a custom error message and redirect the user back to the login page.

I've searched for solutions and looked at related questions on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find a clear answer that addresses my specific issue.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to handle authentication errors in Flask and customize the error message? Additionally, if you can provide code examples or point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your code to the question. A paraphrase is not enough to help you in a targeted manner.

Comment: Try looking at [Login authentication with Flask](https://pythonspot.com/login-authentication-with-flask/).